# Jquery .Load but instead of replace prepend

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am trying to load in some text from another page, however I want to prepend it rather than replace.

So at the moment I have:

```
$('#01-L1-00-Container').load('Page.aspx #Q-01-L1-00');
```

But '01-L1-00-Container' includes some content I need to keep and cannot overwrite. How do I prepend instead of replace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either do this:

```
$("#01-L1-00-Container").prepend( $("<div>").load("Page.aspx #Q-01-L1-00"));
```

Or

```
$("<div>").load("Page.aspx #Q-01-L1-00", function() {
      $("#01-L1-00-Container").prepend($(this).find("#Q-01-L1-00").html());
});
```

These both work by **creating** a div in the dom, loading the new page (with ajax) into that **div** and then prepending the newly created div to the container.

Comment: Perfect! I used the top one and instead of using a div I used a span instead as I didn't want a line break which div gave me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't want to append the data to some other element inside the container, you can't do this with `.load` alone, but it is easy:

```
$.get('Page.aspx').done(function (html) {
   $(html).find('#Q-01-L1-00').prependTo("#01-L1-00-Container');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead :

```
$("#01-L1-00-Container").prepend($("<div />").load("URL of Page"));
```

Hope this will help !!

Comment: Thanks for replying. What purpose does the <div /> have though? Or should I replace that with #Q-01-L1-00?

Comment: @user1891740, the **<div />** is a dynamic DOM element container which holds the data fetched from URL. After fetching stuff it will prepend the data in your desired div element